# Category permalink in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

What is category permalink in wordpress?

```
     get_post_meta($post->ID, '_category_permalink', true);
```

What is the output for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

permalink means seo friendly url of category, for get permalink you can use below code

```
$category_link = get_category_link( $category_id );
```

Answer (score 0):

The given code will output nothing because [`get_post_meta`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta) is useful for the `meta_values` associated with the **post**.

So to get category link, there is one function in wordpress which is [`get_category_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_category_link) but it has **required** parameter `category_id`. So you eventually you also need category ID also to get category link.

To get category ID,you can use [`get_the_category`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_category) and you can do something like ,

```
$cat_name = get_the_category($post->ID);
```

So it will give you an array of object(If you want to see that array object, simply do `var_dump($cat_name)`) and you can get `category_ID` from that object.

So now you will have `category link` which you can get by `get_category_link($cat_name[0]->cat_ID)`.

Final code to get category link :

```
    $cat_name = get_the_category($post->ID);
    echo get_category_link($cat_name[0]->cat_ID);
```

**NOTE :** If you want link in loop, you can simply use `the_category`